# How to get a list of contents of a shared folder in OneDrive

Tags: c#, onedrive

I want to download all files shared with me using C#. I want to know how get the direct links of the files in OneDrive shared folder to use in code like this:

```
WebClient clientDownload = new WebClient();

clientDownload.DownloadFile("https://onedrive.live.com/download?resid=65717E82823D76!12190&authkey=!AK56zXTrSt_LnQ0&itht=file%2cdocx,"@"C:\Users\Desktop\example.zip");
```